# Pass the access token to resource server from authorisation server

Tags: c#, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have separated the Authorisation server and the resource sever. I'm able to validate the client and the resource owner in the Authorisation and server and generate an access token. But how do I pass it resource sever, I passed in the header but I still get the "Authorization has been denied for this request".

I followed this http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

and gave the same MachineKey for both servers but no luck. Does anyone know how this works? how the Auth server and the resource sever communicate with each other?

Comment: If you are following a specific tutorial, and you have no code to show or error message, there is nothing we can do about it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Its not really a code related question, I'm only asking how the authorisation server and the resource server communicate with each other. for example is there any other way other than the machine key to create a mutual bond between the two servers

Comment: They don't communicate with each other.

Comment: @john how does the resource server identify whether the token is valid or not?

Comment: No session is created. Instead, your claims are encrypted in the access token using the machine key. If you have the same machine key on another machine, you can decrypt the access token and get access to the claims stored within.

Comment: I found what was wrong. Securiry.OAuth NuGet package has to match on both projects. ie the version number. thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. Securiry.OAuth NuGet package has to match on both projects. ie the version number. So installed the same version for both projects